# Failure migrating Android project from IDEA 11 to DEA 12 with libs

Tags: android, import, intellij-idea, libs

I have an Android project which I have been working on using IDEA 11 without any problem. Switching to IDEA 12 I have a weired problem when importing classes from jars in my lib folder. Package names are resolved, but classes names aren't. Here is a screenshot of the same project, left with IDEA 11, right with IDEA 12. https://i.stack.imgur.com/e40l0.png

If I end the import with the * wildcard importation and build succeed.
Both IDE are using the same project folder and files, both IDE show the same project settings like this screenshot shows (left IDEA 11, right IDEA 12).
https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1YSi.jpg

Has anyone a clue of what is going on?
My environnement is OSX Mountain Lion with Android dev kit up to date.

Thanks!

Comment: Does `File` | `Invalidate Caches` help?

Comment: Very short answer with big results! Yes, indeed, it helped. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If compiler works fine, but IDEA highlights code with errors, it usually means that IDEA internal caches are corrupted and should be invalidated. It can be done using `File` | `Invalidate Caches` menu.